# Artificial Neural Network with continuous and binary variables

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, binary-data, continuous-data

I have a dataset with numerical (continuous) and categorical variables. I want to fit an artificial neural network. To do so, I have transformed my categorical variables by using the 1-of-k method, so I now have a bunch of binary variables. I am using the `Neuralnet` package in R to fit my ANN model.

From a theoretical point of view: **is there any problem by mixing the continuous and binary variables in the same model?**

1-of-k method is explained below:

The dat set

```
 [1] Sweden
 [2] India
```

becomes

```
    Sweden    India
[1]    1       0
[2]    0       1
```

Comment: Neural networks are basically generalized linear models so there shouldn't be an issue theoretically. However, I would read the documentation to be sure it can handle your data as factors (if that's how it's laid out); otherwise, binary variables should be handled well by an ANN

Comment: @Jon, Thanks for your input. I am using 1-of-k method  to avoid categorical data so I dont have factors in my model

Comment: No idea what `1-of-k` means. You may want to explain this in your post for readers such as myself.

Comment: @Jon I thought it was commonly known, sorry for that.. I have explained it now